# Is there a change to iOS 10+ that changes the display sequence of permission dialogs?

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios10, user-permissions

I have a Xamarin.iOS app that, on a fresh install of the app, prompts the user to allow access to location and to request permission for push notifications. Prior to iOS 10, the location request came first, and then the notification request appeared after the user responded to the first prompt. On iOS 10+, these dialogs seem to pop up at the same time. The notification prompt appears for just a split second before the location prompt appears. It then waits for the user to respond, and then shows the notification prompt. Is there a change that was made to iOS 10+ that affected the timing of when the permission prompts are displayed to the user?

For more information, the code uses CLLocationManger.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization to request location access and UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization to request permission for push notifications.

Comment: Show some code that demos the problem you are having.

Comment: I think it is default behavior after iOS 10+, to avoid the alert pop up together, you can control the `Request Authorization` at different time,  for example you can call `CLLocationManger.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization` when the app needs to locate instead of  the app start up.